# HTML Attributes item*

Tags: html

What are `itemprop`, `itemid`, `itemscope`, `itemref`, `itemtype`?

I've seen many websites that have these kind of attributes.

What are the uses of those?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemid (all those remaining attributes are listed at the bottom)

Comment: What effort did you make to find these definitions that are widely published on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The `item*` attributes are [global HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/) that are related to [schema.org](https://schema.org/). Have a look at their [FAQ](https://schema.org/docs/faq.html#0), especially the first one for a better understanding of what this is all about.